# How to temporarily store a image within same aspx page, not using the filesystem ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jcrop

I am using asp.net webforms together with jcrop (cropping image after fileupload)..

This example i have here base the temporary image storing to the filesystem, but.. due to azure i cannot (and won't) do that..

Soo.. how can i have the same functionality *without* saving to disk ? This means... i would like to have a stream all across the line if possible..

```
public partial class UserConfig : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "images\\";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean FileOK = false;
        Boolean FileSaved = false;

        if (Upload.HasFile)
        {
            Session["WorkingImage"] = Upload.FileName;
            String FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Session["WorkingImage"].ToString()).ToLower();
            String[] allowedExtensions = { ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".gif" };
            for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
            {
                if (FileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
                {
                    FileOK = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (FileOK)
        {
            try
            {
                Upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + Session["WorkingImage"]);
                FileSaved = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = "File could not be uploaded." + ex.Message.ToString();
                lblError.Visible = true;
                FileSaved = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type.";
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }

        if (FileSaved)
        {
            pnlUpload.Visible = false;
            pnlCrop.Visible = true;
            imgCrop.ImageUrl = "images/" + Session["WorkingImage"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ImageName = Session["WorkingImage"].ToString();
        int w = Convert.ToInt32(W.Value);
        int h = Convert.ToInt32(H.Value);
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(X.Value);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(Y.Value);

        byte[] CropImage = Crop(path + ImageName, w, h, x, y);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length);
            using (SD.Image CroppedImage = SD.Image.FromStream(ms, true))
            {
                string SaveTo = path + "crop" + ImageName;
                CroppedImage.Save(SaveTo, CroppedImage.RawFormat);
                pnlCrop.Visible = false;
                pnlCropped.Visible = true;
                imgCropped.ImageUrl = "images/crop" + ImageName;
            }
        }
    }

    static byte[] Crop(string Img, int Width, int Height, int X, int Y)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SD.Image OriginalImage = SD.Image.FromFile(Img))
            {
                using (SD.Bitmap bmp = new SD.Bitmap(Width, Height))
                {
                    bmp.SetResolution(OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution, OriginalImage.VerticalResolution);
                    using (SD.Graphics Graphic = SD.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                    {
                        Graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                        Graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        Graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), X, Y, Width, Height, SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        bmp.Save(ms, OriginalImage.RawFormat);
                        return ms.GetBuffer();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw (Ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want a stream, put it in session. You have to be careful as too much in the session can hit the memory barrier and cause the application pool to recycle. You could try to serialize it to the viewstate via a serialized string, but that can really slow the roundtrip as the viewstate bloats.

Comment: Yeah @Mark.. done mistakes with especially Session, and somewhat ViewState before.., so not very eager going on that trip again :)

Comment: `due to azure`  this needs some more explanation.  What about Azure makes you reluctant to store the image on disk?

Comment: That's a good point @Sam :) It's been a while since i've been messing around with storing data on the filesystem when using Azure Websites.. 
Remember i had a _very_ hard time the last time i tried to tweak this around to work.

So... maybe you know something i dont know about storing files on the filesystem when using Azure ?

Comment: I use the Azure SDK (installed via NuGet), and the Azure Storage API (CloudStorageAccount, CloudBlobClient, CloudBlobContainer, CloudBlockBlob).  Azure storage is accessible from Azure Websites, and once you upload a file, that file is accessible via a standard URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not opposed to using Azure Storage, here's a class I use.  It's designed for uploading images and pdfs, but I'm sure you can modify it to fit your needs.

Usage:

```
Dim storage As AzureStorage = New AzureStorage("storage name", "storage key")
    storage.UploadFile("directory name", "filename", fileStream)
```

Once uploaded your file is accessible via url:

```
http://yourdomain.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/filename
```

Helper class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob


'
'   See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135715.aspx for naming guidelines.
'

Public Class AzureStorage

    Public Sub New(ByVal storageName As String, ByVal storageKey As String)

        Me.StorageName = storageName
        Me.StorageKey = storageKey

    End Sub



    Private Function GetStorageAccount() As CloudStorageAccount

        Dim result As CloudStorageAccount = New CloudStorageAccount(New StorageCredentials(StorageName, StorageKey), True)

        Return result

    End Function



    Private Function GetBlobContainer(ByVal name As String) As CloudBlobContainer

        Dim account As CloudStorageAccount = GetStorageAccount()
        Dim client As CloudBlobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient
        Dim result As CloudBlobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(name)

        result.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob)

        Return result

    End Function



    Private Function GetBlob(ByVal containerName As String, ByVal name As String) As CloudBlockBlob

        Dim container As CloudBlobContainer = GetBlobContainer(containerName)
        Dim result As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name)

        Return result

    End Function



    Public Sub UploadFlyer(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal stream As Stream)

        UploadFile("flyers", fileName, stream)

    End Sub



    Public Sub UploadLogo(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal stream As Stream)

        UploadFile("class-logos", fileName, stream)

    End Sub



    Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal containerName As String, ByVal fileName As String, ByVal stream As Stream)

        Dim blob As CloudBlockBlob = GetBlob(containerName, fileName)
        Dim targetMaximumSize As Int32 = 144
        Dim width As Int32 = targetMaximumSize
        Dim height As Int32 = targetMaximumSize
        Dim coefficient As Decimal = 1
        Dim imageStream As Stream = New MemoryStream

        Dim formats As Dictionary(Of String, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat) = New Dictionary(Of String, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat)
        Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(fileName).Trim.ToLower

        formats.Add(".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        formats.Add(".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

        '
        '   Resize source image to max 144px (2") to a side
        '
        If formats.ContainsKey(extension) Then
            Using sourceImage As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream)
                coefficient = targetMaximumSize / Math.Max(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height)
                If coefficient < 1 Then
                    width = sourceImage.Width * coefficient
                    height = sourceImage.Height * coefficient
                    Using targetImage As System.Drawing.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height)
                        Using graphics As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(targetImage)
                            graphics.DrawImage(sourceImage, targetImage.GetBounds(System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel), sourceImage.GetBounds(System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel), Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
                        End Using
                        targetImage.Save(imageStream, formats(extension))
                    End Using
                Else
                    sourceImage.Save(imageStream, formats(extension))
                End If
            End Using

            imageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            blob.UploadFromStream(imageStream)
        Else
            blob.UploadFromStream(stream)
        End If
        imageStream.Dispose()

    End Sub



    Public Sub DeleteFile(ByVal containerName As String, ByVal fileName As String)

        Dim blob As CloudBlockBlob = GetBlob(containerName, fileName)

        blob.DeleteIfExists(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots)

    End Sub



    Public Property StorageName As String = String.Empty

    Public Property StorageKey As String = String.Empty

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam :) I'll go through it tomorrow afternoon, since i have to get to bed for a moroccan wedding (dooh!).. Not all fun on vacation :) 

I have a storage already set for uploading images, but i like the way you are uploading through "UploadFile" method.. :) I'll try that out tomorrow.. Either though.. i will need a two step (two different pages OR.. a updatepanel update to make this work :)

Comment: Correct. This method would require a round-trip to the server, either via page reload or XHR. It doesn't answer the question as asked, but you may find it useful.  I hope the wedding is fun!